# How to inherit styles from another styled component and turning regular component into styled component at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am using StyledComponents stying framework and This is my regular react component

```
const SelectButton = ({className,children, ...rest}) => {
  return (
     <select className = {className}{...rest}>
             {children}
          </select>
  );
}
```

I want to turn this component into styled component by calling styled() function and for that purpose I have attached className prop to DOM element of my react component (SelectButton).

```
export const StyledSelectButton = styled(SelectButton);
```

But instead of putting the css in this styled component, I want to inherit from different styled component which is StyledButton.js, which has following css properties.

```
export const StyledButton = styled(Button).attrs(({ type }) => ({
  type: type || "button",
}))
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0.8rem 2rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: ${({ primary }) => (primary ? "#646ff0" : "#cccdde")};
  color: ${({ primary }) => (primary ? "white" : "#646681")};
  .__select {
    color: #585858;
    font-family: Poppins;
    padding: 1rem;
    border: none;
    background-color: #cccdde;
    width: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
  };
```

How can I achieve that?

I have tried doing this way , but I am repeating my code.

```
export const StyledSelectButton = styled(SelectButton)
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0.8rem 2rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: ${({ primary }) => (primary ? "#646ff0" : "#cccdde")};
  color: ${({ primary }) => (primary ? "white" : "#646681")};
  &__select {
    color: #585858;
    font-family: Poppins;
    padding: 1rem;
    border: none;
    background-color: #cccdde;
    width: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
import styled, {css} from "styled-components";
import { StyledButton } from './Button';

  const style = css`
  color: #585858;
  font-family: Poppins;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: none;
  background-color: #cccdde;
  width: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
`;
```

Using function declaration method:

```
export function StyledSelectButton({ className, children, ...rest }){
   return (
     <select className={className} {...rest}>
       {children}
     </select>
   );
 };
```

To turn this component into a styled component, pass it to the styled() function.

```
StyledSelectButton = styled(StyledButton).attrs((props) => ({
    as: "select"
}))`
  ${style}
`;
```